# Starting Gnat Studio with Alire fails

Tags: ada, gnat

I have had a try at using Gnat Studio with the Alire package manager. Launching Gnat Studio using the 'alr edit' command is causing Gnat Studio to crash. I have had a look at the log file and there are several .dll files causing exceptions. The file entries are like this:

`[PROJECTS.EXCEPTIONS] Unexpected exception: raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : gnatcoll-projects.adb:5729 index check failed _PROJECTS.EXCEPTIONS_ [C:\GNATSTUDIO\bin\gps.libgnatcoll\libgnatcoll.dll] _PROJECTS.EXCEPTIONS_ 0x7ffc78dcecb8 ??? at ???`

Gnat Studio opens in an 'inconsistent state' and crashes.

Regards
Mike

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems using alire with GNAT Studio.
GNAT Studio seems to need some environment variables set by alire
to be available at project startup.

I found a GNAT plugin that automatically sets those on project start, but
I had to adapt it to work for alire 1.1.x.
My version is on GitHub at https://github.com/mhatzl/gps_alire.

Close GNAT Studio and copy the python file of the repo inside `.gnatstudio/plug-ins`, which should be located in your user directory.

After that, GNAT Studio should be able to setup everything needed from alire if you open your `.gpr` file.

**Note:** This works for me on Windows 10.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I think I will just use visual studio code, which is working.